# Redux state not updating in react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Seen this asked many times but I have a case where many suggested fixes are already implemented.

The section of the store `platform` is being mutated by a set of async functions dispatching actions.

```
export const actionHandlers: ActionHandler<PlatformActionTypes, IPlatformState> = {
  [PlatformActionTypes.SET_PRODUCT]: (state: IPlatformState, action: ISetProductAction) => ({ ...state, product: action.payload }),
  [PlatformActionTypes.SET_PRODUCT_GROUPS]: (state: IPlatformState, action: ISetProductGroupsAction) => ({ ...state, productGroups: action.payload }),
  [PlatformActionTypes.TOGGLE_SELECTED_PRODUCTS]: (state: IPlatformState, action: IToggleProductAction) => ({ ...state, productGroups: action.payload }),
  [PlatformActionTypes.SET_PRODUCT_GROUP_DATA]: (state: IPlatformState, action: ISetProductGroupData) => {
    const { title } = action.payload;
    const index = state.productGroups.findIndex((group) => group.title = title);

    state.productGroups.splice(index, 1, action.payload);

    return state;
  }
};


export default function designstartReducer(state: IPlatformState = INITIAL_STATE, action: IPlatformAction) {
  const handler = actionHandlers[action.type];

  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}
```

container

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onFetchProductDetails: fetchPlatform,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IAppState) => ({
  ...state.platform,
});

const connected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Platform);

export default analytics.trackPage({ componentName: 'Platform' })(connected);
```

Redux dev tools after api responses:

[image]

I cannot for the life of me work out why I still have the initial state object in my component despite Redux Dev tools showing the reducers working and the store containing the fetched data.

One reason I can think of is that state.platform shape hasn't changed and hence the update is not triggered in the component?

Comment: where exactly you mutated state.platform? maybe you see in Redux dev tools the INITIAL_STATE?

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing a new copy of 'platform' in the branch of reducers which the same action type works.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Biggest schoolboy error of my life.

My store creation was in the render method of a component triggering a lot of re-renders meaning the store was being reset.